# What I'm doing wrong with this Wacom driver installation?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, apt, lubuntu

I'm trying to install [Linux Wacom drivers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/) on Lubuntu 14 (32bit) but they never work on my [Motion LE 1700 Tablet PC](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1372076/motion-le1700-tablet-pc.html).

This a computer/tablet, the pen is detected directly on the screen and is not attached via USB. [Linux Mint XFCE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php), [Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.org/) and Windows 8 detect the pen right out of the box, however Lubuntu is unable to do so.

The pen has the same technology as a Wacom Intuos, so "input-wacom" drivers should work as [reported here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=830496&highlight=motion).

`Serial Wacom Tablet stylus` and `Serial Wacom Tablet eraser` [should appear in the xinput list](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217121), however they are missing in Lubuntu.

I have the following packages installed in [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/action.html) (Synaptic as in the Linux package manager, not touchpad devices), but they don't make any difference, the pen is still unrecognized:

- kde-config-tablet 2.0-2
- libwacom-common 0.8-1
- libwacom-dev 0.8-1
- libwacom2 0.8-1
- libwacom2-dbg 0.8-1
- xserver-xorg-input-wacom 1:025.0-0ubuntu1
- xserver-xorg-input-wacom-db 1:025.0-0ubuntu

Here's my last attempt to install the driver:

```
lonrot@motionLu:~$ wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/linuxwacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2cd Escritorio
--2015-01-23 18:52:57--  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/linuxwacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2cd
Resolviendo prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59
Conectando con prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)[216.34.181.59]:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 404 Not Found
2015-01-23 18:52:57 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2015-01-23 18:52:57--  http://escritorio/
Resolviendo escritorio (escritorio)... falló: Nombre o servicio desconocido.
wget: no se pudo resolver la dirección del equipo “escritorio”
lonrot@motionLu:~$ 
lonrot@motionLu:~$ wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/linuxwacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2
--2015-01-23 18:53:02--  http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/linuxwacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2
Resolviendo prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59
Conectando con prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)[216.34.181.59]:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 301 Moved Permanently
Ubicación: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2 [siguiente]
--2015-01-23 18:53:02--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2
Resolviendo downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.59
Conectando con downloads.sourceforge.net (downloads.sourceforge.net)[216.34.181.59]:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 302 Found
Ubicación: http://colocrossing.dl.sourceforge.net/project/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2 [siguiente]
--2015-01-23 18:53:03--  http://colocrossing.dl.sourceforge.net/project/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2
Resolviendo colocrossing.dl.sourceforge.net (colocrossing.dl.sourceforge.net)... 75.127.11.234
Conectando con colocrossing.dl.sourceforge.net (colocrossing.dl.sourceforge.net)[75.127.11.234]:80... conectado.
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: 102949 (101K) [application/octet-stream]
Grabando a: “input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2”

100%[======================================>] 102 949      191KB/s   en 0,5s   

2015-01-23 18:53:04 (191 KB/s) - “input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2” guardado [102949/102949]

lonrot@motionLu:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for lonrot: 

Lo sentimos, vuelva a intentarlo.
[sudo] password for lonrot: 
Ign http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease                      
Ign http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports InRelease                    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                            
Des:1 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg [933 B]          
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release.gpg                  
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                
Des:2 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release [62,0 kB]            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Obj http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports Release                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease                       
Obj http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                  
Obj http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease                                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Des:3 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg [933 B]           
Des:4 http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages [1 206 B]                 
Obj http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                                
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                           
Des:5 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release [62,0 kB]             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                                  
Des:6 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Sources [62,5 kB]       
Obj http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release                                    
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Des:7 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Sources [11,8 kB]   
Des:8 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources [719 B]   
Des:9 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main i386 Packages [160 kB]  
Des:10 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages [63,2 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Obj http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources                               
Des:11 http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [2 233 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg                                
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Sources                       
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Sources                     
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                     
Obj http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Sources           
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe i386 Packages                 
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse i386 Packages               
Obj http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free i386 Packages                         
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-es                    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-es              
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Translation-en              
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-es                
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Translation-en                
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Translation-en            
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Translation-en        
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Sources                 
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Sources             
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main i386 Packages           
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/main Translation-en          
Obj http://cr.archive.ubuntu.com utopic-backports/universe Translation-en      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                                    
Des:12 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources [37,3 kB]       
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-es_CR                         
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-es                            
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Des:13 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources [7 066 B]   
Des:14 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources [719 B]   
Des:15 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main i386 Packages [109 kB]  
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-es_CR                     
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-es                        
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Translation-en                        
Des:16 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe i386 Packages [46,5 kB]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-es_CR                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-es                        
Des:17 http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2 233 B]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en                        
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                   
Obj http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Translation-en        
Obj http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en  
Obj http://security.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Translation-en    
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources                               
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-es_CR                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-es                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-es_CR                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-es                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                        
Descargados 629 kB en 26seg. (24,1 kB/s)                                       
W: Imposible obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Imposible obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Imposible obtener http://ppa.launchpad.net/lekensteyn/wacom-tablet/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Algunos archivos de índice fallaron al descargar. Se han ignorado, o se han utilizado unos antiguos en su lugar
E: No se pudo bloquear /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Recurso no disponible temporalmente)
E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio de administración (/var/lib/dpkg/), ¿quizás haya algún otro proceso utilizándolo?
lonrot@motionLu:~$ tar xjvf input-wacom-0.13.0.tar.bz2
input-wacom-0.13.0/
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/Makefile.in
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/wacom.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/wacom_sys.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/wacom_w8001.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/wacom_wac.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.30/wacom_wac.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/Makefile.in
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/wacom.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/wacom_sys.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/wacom_w8001.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/wacom_wac.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.36/wacom_wac.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/Makefile.in
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_sys.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_w8001.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/inputattach/
input-wacom-0.13.0/inputattach/inputattach.c
input-wacom-0.13.0/inputattach/README
input-wacom-0.13.0/inputattach/serio-ids.h
input-wacom-0.13.0/README
input-wacom-0.13.0/configure.ac
input-wacom-0.13.0/aclocal.m4
input-wacom-0.13.0/Makefile.am
input-wacom-0.13.0/Makefile.in
input-wacom-0.13.0/config.h.in
input-wacom-0.13.0/configure
input-wacom-0.13.0/AUTHORS
input-wacom-0.13.0/COPYING
input-wacom-0.13.0/ChangeLog
input-wacom-0.13.0/INSTALL
input-wacom-0.13.0/NEWS
input-wacom-0.13.0/install-sh
input-wacom-0.13.0/missing
lonrot@motionLu:~$ cd input-wacom-0.13.0
lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
bash: ./autogen.sh: No existe el archivo o el directorio
lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/lonrot
bash: ./autogen.sh: No existe el archivo o el directorio
lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking for kernel type... Linux
checking for linux-based kernel... yes
checking for kernel source/headers... /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/build
checking kernel version... 3.16.0-29-generic

configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating 2.6.30/Makefile
config.status: creating 2.6.36/Makefile
config.status: creating 2.6.38/Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
Making all in 2.6.38
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38'
    Building input-wacom drivers for 2.6 kernel.
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/build M=/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-29-generic'
  LD      /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.o
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c: In function ‘wacom_pl_irq’:
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:79:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dbg’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   dbg("wacom_pl_irq: received unknown report #%d", data[0]);
   ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c: In function ‘wacom_setup_input_capabilities’:
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1381:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
    input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 16);
    ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1414:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
    input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 2);
    ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1476:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
     input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 16);
     ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1482:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
     input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 2);
     ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-29-generic'
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38'
Makefile:266: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
Makefile:200: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

----------------------------------------
  BUILD ENVIRONMENT:
       linux kernel - yes 2.6.38
      kernel source - yes /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/build

Your wacom.ko is available under 
    /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38
If you have an USB device, you can copy the driver by:
    cp 2.6.38/wacom.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/input/tablet
If you have a serial device, please copy the driver by:
    cp 2.6.38/wacom_w8001.ko /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen

NOTE: The kernel drivers included in this package are only
tested with the X Wacom driver built from xf86-input-wacom.
 If you are running an X server version older than 1.7, 
please use the drivers provided by linuxwacom package.

lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
Making all in 2.6.38
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38'
    Building input-wacom drivers for 2.6 kernel.
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/build M=/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-29-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.o
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c: In function ‘wacom_pl_irq’:
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:79:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘dbg’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   dbg("wacom_pl_irq: received unknown report #%d", data[0]);
   ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c: In function ‘wacom_setup_input_capabilities’:
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1381:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
    input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 16);
    ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1414:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
    input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 2);
    ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1476:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
     input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 16);
     ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:1482:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘input_mt_init_slots’
     input_mt_init_slots(input_dev, 2);
     ^
In file included from /home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.c:17:0:
include/linux/input/mt.h:79:5: note: declared here
 int input_mt_init_slots(struct input_dev *dev, unsigned int num_slots,
     ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:257: recipe for target '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38/wacom_wac.o] Error 1
Makefile:1345: recipe for target '_module_/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-29-generic'
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38'
Makefile:266: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
Makefile:200: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$ sudo make install
Making install in 2.6.38
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'install'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0/2.6.38'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lonrot/input-wacom-0.13.0'
lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$ ^C
lonrot@motionLu:~/input-wacom-0.13.0$
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you installing touchpad device driver for a Wacom pen? Synaptic is a touch pad...or is it a tool?

Comment: It is a tool to install packages in Linux:
http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/action.html

Comment: Lubuntu is a pretty light-weight distro that is missing a lot in the way of drivers and supporting components.  The fact that the driver worked with a number of other Linux distros points to Lubuntu (or what it is missing) as the problem.  A couple of directions I would look: 1) Specialists (tech support for Motion, Wacom, maybe Lubuntu forums).  2) Try other lightweight distros; some are much better than others at handling hardware.  3) Compare the Lubuntu package contents to that of another Ubuntu-based distro that works (like Mint), to find the differences.

Comment: Just noticed that the last action in your screen activity listing is downloading the driver tarball.  I don't believe Synaptic can install a tarball; those generally require a manual installation process.  Did you do that?  (Just wanted to verify that the problem isn't that the driver isn't actually installed.)

Comment: Yes it's a Linux Wacom Driver, Lubuntu has Wacom legacy drivers, this tar is the latest version, however it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by recreating an older Ubuntu file  `69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules` in  `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules/` thanks to [Phi at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541505/thinkpad-x41-tablet-wacom-stylus-stopped-working-on-lubuntu-14-10).

The Stylus pen and eraser are detected in the xinput list and both have pressure sensitivity.

I still have no idea how to update Wacom drivers properly, but the stylus works perfectly fine for the time being.

I quote Phi's intructions below:

> I just removed the whole folder /lib/udev/rules.d/69-wacom.rules/
>   (Actually I moved it to my Desktop just in case I need it again.)
>
> Then I added the following file (named
>   69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules) instead of the removed folder (I
>   have copied the file from the ubuntu installed on my lenovo X61
>   Tablet):

`/lib/udev/rules.d/69-xserver-xorg-input-wacom.rules`

```
# udev rules for wacom tablets.
# These rules were compiled for the Debian GNU/Linux distribution,
# but others may, and indeed are encouraged to, use them also.
#
# Should you do so, PLEASE CO-ORDINATE ANY CHANGES OR ADDITIONS
# of new devices with Ron <ron@debian.org> so that we can try
# to present users with a standard set of device nodes which
# they can rely on across the board.

# Catch the serial tablets and tell X that's what they are
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="pnp", ATTR{id}=="WACf*", ENV{NAME}="Serial Wacom Tablet"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="pnp", ATTR{id}=="FUJ*", ENV{NAME}="Serial Wacom Tablet"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp", ATTRS{id}=="WACf*", ENV{ID_INPUT}="1", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="1"
ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp", ATTRS{id}=="FUJ*", ENV{ID_INPUT}="1", ENV{ID_INPUT_TABLET}="1"

KERNEL!="event[0-9]*", GOTO="wacom_end"

# Port specific link for users of multiple tablets of the same type.
# The ID_PATH variable is set by the "path_id" script in an earlier rule file.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ENV{ID_PATH}=="?*", SYMLINK="input/by-path/$env{ID_PATH}-wacom"

# Multiple interface support for stylus and touch devices.
DRIVERS=="wacom", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}="stylus"
DRIVERS=="wacom", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="01", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}="touch"

# Type-named links for multiple tablets.  If you want to use multiple
# tablets of the _same_ type, you will probably need to use the links
# from /dev/input/by-path to identify which is plugged into what usb
# port.  For different tablet types though, just pick your links from
# the list below.
#
# We override SYMLINK for tabletpc devices because the by-path link
# is not required with such devices, there will only ever be one.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-penpartner"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq_partner"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0010", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0011", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire2-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0012", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire2-5x7"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0013", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire3"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0014", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire3-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0015", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire4-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0016", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire4-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0017", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboofun-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0018", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboofun-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0019", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboo1-medium"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0021", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0022", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-9x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0023", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-12x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0024", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos-12x18"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0030", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl400"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0031", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl500"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0032", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl600"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0033", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl600sx"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0034", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl550"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0035", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl800"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0037", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl700"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0038", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-pl510"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0039", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtu710"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="003f", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq21ux"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0041", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0042", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-9x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0044", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-12x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0045", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-12x18"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0047", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos2-6x8a"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0060", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-volito"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0061", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-penstation2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0062", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-volito2-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0063", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-volito2-2x3"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0064", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-penpartner2"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0065", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboo"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0069", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-bamboo1"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0081", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-graphire_bt-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0090",  SYMLINK="input/tablet-tpc90"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0093",  SYMLINK="input/tablet-tpc93-$env{WACOM_TYPE}"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="009a",  SYMLINK="input/tablet-tpc9a-$env{WACOM_TYPE}"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b0", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-4x5"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b1", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-6x8"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b2", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-9x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b3", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-12x12"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b4", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-12x19"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b5", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-6x11"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b7", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos3-4x6"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b8", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-4x6"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00b9", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-6x9"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00ba", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-8x13"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00bb", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-intuos4-12x19"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c0", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtf521"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c4", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtf720"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c5", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq20wsx"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c6", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-cintiq12wx"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00c7", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}!="touch", SYMLINK+="input/tablet-dtu1931"

# Convenience links for the common case of a single tablet.  We could do just this:
#ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", SYMLINK+="input/wacom-$env{WACOM_TYPE}"
# but for legacy reasons, we keep the input/wacom link as the generic stylus device.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}!="touch", SYMLINK+="input/wacom"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ENV{WACOM_TYPE}=="touch", SYMLINK+="input/wacom-touch"

# Check and repossess the device if a module other than the wacom one
# is already bound to it.
#
# We probably don't need this one in the Real World anymore ...
# See the old wacom-tools package if we actually do need to resurrect the
# check_driver script for this again.
#ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ACTION=="add", RUN+="check_driver wacom $devpath $env{ID_BUS}"

LABEL="wacom_end"
```